# Unpack error in a function that converts float to binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, binary, unpack

I am trying to make a Python function that takes a float number, and converts it to a string with its binary (considering the fractional part too, separated by a dot), but for some values ​-such as 0.5, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 , 0.05, ...- it gives the following error:

```
line 7, in floatToBinary integerPart, fractionalPart = str((convertDecimal(fractional))*2).split(".")
ValueError: Not enough values ​​to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Functions:

```
def floatToBinary(floatNumber, decimalPlaces):
    integerPart, fractionalPart = str(floatNumber).split(".")
    integerPart = int(integerPart)
    fractionalPart = int(fractionalPart)
    result = bin(integerPart).lstrip("0b") + "."
    for i in range(decimalPlaces):
        integerPart, fractionalPart = str((convertDecimal(fractionalPart))*2).split(".")
        fractionalPart = int(fractionalPart)
        result += integerPart
    return result

def convertDecimal(n):
    while n > 1:
        n /= 10
    return n
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The function convertDecimal returns 0 when n = 0. So there is no '.' to split. 
You can fix that by casting the return value as float

```
def convertDecimal(n):
    while n > 1:
        n /= 10
    return float(n)
```